# Using XAMPP Vhosts its not using DocumentRoot

Tags: apache-http-server, xampp

I am trying to use xampp vhosts and i have filled in the DocumentRoot however its not going to the document root instead its going to the htdocs root instead. With the domain 
My hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 www.testsite.com
127.0.0.1 testsite.com

127.0.0.1 www.testsite-cms.com
127.0.0.1 testsite-cms.com

127.0.0.1 localapp.com
127.0.0.1 www.localapp.com
```

My vhosts file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/testsite"
ServerName testsite.com
ServerAlias www.testsite.com
<Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/testsite">
AllowOverride All
Require all Granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/cms"
ServerName testsite-cms.com
ServerAlias www.testsite-cms.com
<Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/cms">
AllowOverride All
Require all Granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/www"
ServerName localapp.com
ServerAlias www.localapp.com
<Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/www">
AllowOverride All
Require all Granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `NameVirtualHost *:80` at the top of your configuration. Otherwise the server will resolve the virtual host based on IP which always matches the first `<VirtualHost>` directive since all of your sites are 127.0.0.1 which localhost resolves to. Since its wildcarded it would also match to your first vhost even if it wasn't localhost if it wasn't specified in your other vhosts as well.

Comment: Ok, im not quite following your meaning so before i declare all my Virtual hosts i should have this: NameVirtualHost *:80 written at the top of the file?

Comment: @DevDaniel Yes, thats correct.